# A basic question on change of limit and integration without using Measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ such that $0 \leq f_n \leq 1$ and such that $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, for every $x \in [0,1]$, then

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx = 0$$.

I have to prove this without suing any measure theory. Under the hypotheses, $f_n$'s are not uniformly convergent. How to change limit and integrals here ?

Comment: "This is to impress you with the power of the Lebesgue integral"? (Rudin, Ex. 2.10)

Comment: @DanielFischer: correct. But the hint tells that there is some other proof. I want to know that.